# Table cell sizing in quirk mode

Tags: html, css

In Firefox 4 and Chrome (unverified in other browsers), the table cell has a small black border on the bottom with `<!DOCTYPE html>` (i.e. html5 mode).  Take it out (i.e. quirk mode) and the border disappears.  I was wondering how can I have the border-less version in html5 mode.  Am I missing something in the stylesheet?

*With small, unintentional border on bottom when rendering with `<!DOCTYPE html>`*
[image: html5]

*Without border on bottom when rendering without `<!DOCTYPE html>`*
[image: quirk]

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table.icon {
        display: inline-table;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 2px 0px;
        border: hidden;
      }

      table.icon td.content {
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: black;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px;
        border: hidden;
      }

      .block {
        width:50px;
        height:100px;
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="icon">
      <tr>
        <td class="content"><img class="block"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no difference, but:

1. icons should not be `img` elements, they should be [background images](http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/)
2. a table with one cell is [not a table at all](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)
3. if you want a border on the bottom of something (or even want to remove the same), use the `border-bottom` property
4. regardless of the differences, you always want a properly included doctype declaration (how you're doing it here is fine)
5. the `type="text/css"` attribute on `style` elements is unnecessary in HTML5
6. while not invalid in HTML5, closing `img` elements in HTML is still goofy unless you require your code to have XML conformity

Comment: Updated with some examples and fixed the mocked up html.  I want the layout without borders, but I am not able to get rid of them no matter how I tweak the stylesheet.

Comment: I'm going with background images and divs instead of single-cell tables as per suggestion.  Cheers